# How to convert string with comma to decimal in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I've got string price with comma at the end and I have to put it into decimal(10,2).

I tried to convert it into numeric with the same precision and scale but still gives me error of potential data loose.

> Error: 0xC02020C5 at Przychód, Data Conversion [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW8tU.png): Data conversion failed while converting column "pr_kwota" (46) to column "Copy of pr_kwota" (10).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Data from flat file(str 50)
[image]

What i tried to do:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use the transformation "Derived Column" instead of "Data Conversion" and probably the issue is the space as well as the comma so you can use this function inside the Derived Column transformation:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)(REPLACE(REPLACE(pr_kwota," ",""),",","."))
```

Comment: Didnt have to additionaly convert data into DT_NUMERIC, after removing comma and space it converted it automatically. Thank you kindly for your time Sir.